# FTP user access limited to one folder

Tags: server, users, ftp, raspberrypi

I have ftp server running on my raspberry pi and I have to users there I want to limit one user's access only to his home folder (/home/user), so when he logs in via ftp he can't go to other folders only his home folder and folders inside his home folder.

Answer (score 1):

Users can be limited to their home directories by uncommenting /etc/vsftpd.conf file:

```
chroot_local_user=YES
```

To limit a specific list of users, allow only their home directories:

```
chroot_list_enable=YES
chroot_list_file=/etc/vsftp.chroot_list
```

Set User HOME Directory:

```
usermod --home /home/user username
```

Set required permission on /home/user

Restart ftp services:

```
/etc/init.d/vsftpd restart
```

Comment: noob question. Where exactly is this file and how do I restart ftp services?

Comment: which ftp tool+version you are using ?

Comment: I've installed apache2 php5 and I was able to connect to Raspberry Pi via sftp, I guess some default apache one

Comment: You can look the file /etc/vsftpd.conf and restart service _/etc/init.d/vsftpd restart_

Comment: the file vsftpd.conf and the /init.d/vsftpd aren't there